# Getting error while calling fit_generator :python Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to make CNN which can predict the animal from image. following are the tools and python version that i am using .
IDE:Spyder 3.2.6 with Anaconda
Tensorflow : version 1.2.1
Keras 2.1.4.
python 3.5

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Conv2D

classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32,3,3,input_shape=(64,64,3),activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 128,activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 1,activation='sigmoid'))
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', matrix = ['accuracy'])

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                                    target_size=(64, 64),
                                                    batch_size=32,
                                                    class_mode='binary') 


test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
                                            target_size=(64, 64),
                                            batch_size=32,
                                            class_mode='binary')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch=(8000/32),
                         epochs=25,
                         validation_data=test_set,
                         validation_steps=(2000/32))
```

but when i run fit_generator method shown above i get following error

```
classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch=(8000/32),
                         epochs=25,
                         validation_data=test_set,
                         validation_steps=(2000/32))
Epoch 1/25
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-f76922930094>", line 5, in <module>
    validation_steps=(2000/32))

  File "C:\Users\fspathan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\fspathan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 1276, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)

  File "C:\Users\fspathan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\fspathan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2224, in fit_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)

  File "C:\Users\fspathan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1883, in train_on_batch
    outputs = self.train_function(ins)

  File "C:\Users\fspathan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2478, in __call__
    **self.session_kwargs)

TypeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'matrix'
```

i've done enogh google and applied all the fixes that were necessary but still no progress . it will be a great help if someone know the solution

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

```
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', matrix = ['accuracy'])
```

You pass the parameter `matrix = ['accuracy']`. This is not any of the parameters accepted by the [`compile`](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#compile) function, and, as documented, extra parameters passed to this function are forwarded to the backend, in the case of TensorFlow to the [`run`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run) method of the internal [`tf.Session`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session) object. However, `matrix` is also not an expected parameter of that function, so it fails when it tries to pass it.

I suspect what you intended to do was to ask Keras to compute the accuracy metric, in which case you would need to pass the `metrics` parameter, not `matrix`:

```
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```